# Angular 6, Template parse Exception

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web

This is my Angular code.

```
<input type="checkbox"  [checked]="fields.check3?.5 != undefined && fields.check3?.5 =='on' ">
```

At runtime, the browser is throwing the following exception.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 5, expected identifier or keyword at column 28 in [fields.check3?.'5' != undefined
```

My data is like this:

```
"check3": {
                "5": "on"
            }
```

Can I not use a number as a property?
How can i use the same data?

Thank you

Comment: You would need to use the bracket notation for that.. `fields.check3?['5']` **not [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation)**. Also based on your condition you do not need the `!=undefined` part, just need `fields.check3?['5'] =='on'`

Answer (score 0):

Safe navigation operator will automatically handle the undefined/null part, in your case you actually do not need the first part of the code also you can use the bracket annotation to access the property using **`['5']`** change your template code as,

```
input type="checkbox"  [checked]="fields.check3?['5'] =='on' ">
```

Comment: `Safe navigation operator will automatically handle the undefined/null part` yes but it has nothing to do in this case. Even if the value of property is `undefined` or has value the second condition is enough (plain javascript & logical condition at play here), OP is using the safe navigation the best as he could. Mentioning why dot notation does not work (Syntax error) here is the crucial part to this question IMO.

Comment: what i meant was this part is not needed checked]="fields.check3?.5 != undefined

Comment: Focus on the OP question "Can I not use a number as a property?"

Comment: yes thats what i have used ['5] even though it  is not explained

Comment: here is some useful information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation

Comment: Thanks @Sajeetharan for the response. Your answer was not entirely correct but i got a way to move forward. I solved it. The save operator is required to check if check3 is null. But yes, ['5'] helped. I am still not clear why I can't use the dot operator to access the number property.

Comment: @Rajani am not sure if you read my comments, it has a link to the MDN which explains wrt the valid property accessors in javascript and talks particularly your use case. If you click on the link it will take you to the page

Comment: @Rajan "In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not." property name '5' is not a valid javascript identifier hence you cannot use dot notation, instead you would need to use the bracket notation